# Bootstrap Grid system and Table element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, navbar, grid-system

Has bootstrap grid system replaced need for table? I mean I can divide a row in 3 parts by a table like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>
```

also by using grid like:

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
 </div>
```

Somehow it looks like I can use grids and table vice-versa. So if I have to place something in my navbar at some particular position what approach should I use? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are not equivalent at all - Bootstrap uses a [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for layout, and [tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) for displaying tabular data.

Generally, this is considered good practice. Tables are difficult to make responsive (to alter layouts for mobile and tablet views), but they are excellent for displaying data similar to the way Microsoft Excel displays data.

I recommend reading the Bootstrap documentation linked above, they explain when to use each.